# JavaFX WebView - not able to capture scroll action

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar

I'm trying to capture all scroll actions (scroll by mouse, scroll by dragging scroll bar) for a `WebView` in JavaFX. I am doing it in the following way, but it's not working. Any suggestions on why it's not working and how to fix this?

```java
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        ScrollBar webViewVerticalScrollBar = getVerticalScrollbar(webView);
        if (webViewVerticalScrollBar != null) {
            webViewVerticalScrollBar
                    .valueProperty()
                    .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        System.out.println("webview: " + newValue);
                    });
            scrollBarListenerAddedForItem2 = true;
        }
    }

});
```

```java
public static ScrollBar getVerticalScrollbar(Node textArea) {
    ScrollBar result = null;
    for (javafx.scene.Node n : textArea.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if (n instanceof ScrollBar) {
            ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) n;
            if (bar.getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) {
                result = bar;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I debugged and found that for the `WebView`, when I have a scroll bar, `getVerticalScrollbar` is returning a non-null value, but still the sysout is not getting called even when I scroll using mouse.

Comment: I’ve noticed WebView scrollbars behave differently from explicitly created scrollbars and scrollpanes, so I’m not surprised they can’t be directly manipulated.  I would instead use WebEngine’s [executeScript](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript(java.lang.String)) method to listen for JavaScript [scroll events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event).

Comment: Alternatively, instrument the parent node's scroll properties: `onScroll`, et al. In addition, please [edit] you question to clarify the goal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do it alternatively with JavaScript Scroll event, and will also try to instrument the parent node's onScroll property

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?  I ask because I just tested with JavaFX 19 and it is working as I would expect it to.

Comment: I tried using javafx 19, and it's still now working.